# Is there a way to make 'edit' mode the default while editing series data in Excel charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

When editing a series for a chart in Excel (2017), the default mode in the dialog boxes for series name, x values, and y values is 'enter' mode. When I use the arrow keys in the box it adds a cell to the entry rather than moving the cursor because of that. I can hit F2 to change it to 'edit' mode which lets me move the cursor with the arrows, but I have to do it for every dialog box, every time I edit a series.

Is there a way to change the default so I don't have to hit F2 every time? I have never found the 'enter' mode to be useful within the context of editing series data and it would be so much more convenient if the default was 'edit' mode.

Comment: The basic settings of excel cannot set the edit mode to the default, maybe you can try VBA.